# How to Match Specific Date with Date Column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to match a specific date with the available dates in Date column (CHECKTIME) but failed to do so.

Formula: `=IF(MATCH(TEXT($I$4,"m/d/yyyy"),TEXT(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],"m/d/yyyy"),0),"Yes")`

Result: `#N/A`

Where I am doing wrong or what can be updated?

Comment: Why are you converting the value to text?

Comment: Because when i evaluated the formula it converts into an integer.

Comment: yes that is what it should do, if both the lookup and the value are both true dates then they are numbers.

Comment: So, what should i do? I want to find the date from the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match will return an error if the value is not found.  If the criteria in an IF returns an error it will error the whole formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$4,Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],0)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

One note this works if both the value being searced and the lookup values are true dates without any time portion to the number stored.

Remember what you see is not what is stored.  Dates are numbers, the number of days since 12/31/1899, with the time being the decimal of a full day.  `1/1/2020  12:00:00 PM` is stored as `43831.5`.  That number is what the Excel sees no matter how the format mask is.  So if it is formatted `yyyy-mm-dd` it will show `2020-01-01` but the number will still be `43831.5`.

If your data has a time portion we can use COUNTIFS instead:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],">="&INT($I$4),Table_CHECKINOUT4[CHECKTIME],"<"&INT($I$4)+1),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott but the Date is available in the column. It should return Yes.

Comment: @MOZ if the date is in the list it will return 'Yes'

Comment: The date is in the list.

Comment: You are correct. Time is also being stored in the list with Date. That is why the result is No. Please suggest how to avoid time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206610/discussion-between-moz-and-scott-craner).